# How to configure AsciidocFX with Path to PlantUML

Tags: asciidoc, plantuml

I am using AsciidocFX version 1.7.4 to edit Asciidoc documents. When working on PlantUML diagrams and creating a syntax error, which is caused by using syntax that is not supported in older versions, I see the following message

```
PlantUML 1.2021.2
This version of PlantUML is 398 days old, so you should consider upgrading...
```

I have the following version installed on my system:

```
PlantUML version 1.2022.3 (Tue Mar 29 09:10:57 PDT 2022)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

Obviously, AsciidocFX finds a different version. How can I configure AsciidocFX to use my latest locally install version? I went through the Settings dialogs as well as looked in the ~/.AsciidocFX-1.7.4 folder but could not find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[planumtl](https://plantuml.com/) consist of a single plantuml.jar file. You should find a `plantuml-1.2021.2.jar` file in your installation folder, under `lib`, delete it and replace it with your own version.